# Send Multipart/formdata with CURL/php

Tags: php, forms, curl, web-scraping, multipartform-data

I am trying to fetch the results of a web page that is generated after a form submission. There are 2 inputs in the form: 1- Name of the town 2- Date. When I inspect the page on Chrome as to what headers are being sent, this is what I get:

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundarymHxte4apsmNuBb5n
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="town"

    CENTER
    ------WebKitFormBoundarymHxte4apsmNuBb5n
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Date_Start"

    17-05-2020
    ------WebKitFormBoundarymHxte4apsmNuBb5n--
```

The boundary, which is in this case "mHxte4apsmNuBb5n" changes with every submission.

I tried this code to no avail:

```
    function curl($url) {

    //POST string
    $postfields['town'] = 'CENTER';
    $postfields['Date_Start'] = '17-05-2020';
    $headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p");

    $options = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE, 
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, 
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,  
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, 
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  
            CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
            CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,

        );

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   
        $data = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);       
        return $data;   
}

$scraped_page = curl("http://...");    
echo $scraped_page;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have all the CURLOPT_* in place, but they are not strictly required for what you want.

If I create a file on my localhost with the code below it works:

```php
<?php

$data = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST );

if ( $data ) {
    print_r( $data );
    exit;
}

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$data = [
    'town'       => 'CENTER',
    'Date_Start' => '17-05-2020',
];

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt_array( $ch, [
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_RESOLVE => [ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ':80:127.0.0.1' ], // Only required on localhost
] );    

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

echo false !== $response
    ? 'result: ' . $response
    : curl_error( $ch );
```

Als, I am using [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php), which might help you to find out what is going on when curl_exec fails.